# The limit of the sum of Rademacher random variables

Tags: probability

I am attempting to find $lim\sqrt{2n}\mathbb{P}(S_{2n}=0)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$,

where $S_{2n}=\frac{\Sigma_{m=1}^{2n}X_{m}}{\sqrt{2n}}$ , and $X_{1}, X_{2}, \dots$ are i.i.d with $P(X_{1} = \pm1)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Could Stirling's formula be helpful here?

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\lim$ using `\lim`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability can be written explicitly,
$$
\mathbb{P}[S_{2n} = 0] = \frac{1}{4^n}{2n \choose n}.
$$
It is simply the number of events where exactly half the $ X_i $ are $+1$ and the other $-1$ (the binomial coefficient), divided by the total number of events ($2^{2n}$).

Now as you mentioned, you may use Stirling's approximation for the binomial coefficient to obtain
$$
{2n \choose n} \sim \frac{\sqrt{4\pi n}}{2\pi n}\frac{(2n)^{2n}}{\mathrm{e}^{2n}}\left(\frac{\mathrm{e}^n}{n^n}\right)^2 = \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}
$$
which means
$$
\sqrt{2n}\mathbb{P}[S_{2n} = 0] \sim \sqrt{\frac{2n}{\pi n}} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}.
$$